# Passing javascript variables into attribute of html object "data-url"

Tags: javascript, html, variables, url

I'm trying to place a variable in my javascript that will go into a url that is an html object. I've tried assigning the attribute "data-url" which is being used in part with an embedded survey form. I've also tried setAttribute without success.

```
<div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://eatforklore.typeform.com/to/XPDPsx?p1=xxxxx&amp;p2=xxxxx&amp;p3=xxxxx&amp;p4=xxxxx" data-text="Mo. 1 Product Reviews" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<script>// <![CDATA[
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('typeform-widget');
a.data-url = "https://eatforklore.typeform.com/to/XPDPsx?p1=" + p1;

(function(){var qs,js,q,s,d=document,gi=d.getElementById,ce=d.createElement,gt=d.getElementsByTagName,id='typef_orm',b='https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/share.typeform.com/';if(!gi.call(d,id)){js=ce.call(d,'script');js.id=id;js.src=b+'widget.js';q=gt.call(d,'script')[0];q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q)}})()
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` is:

1. not what you want - use `getElementsByClassName` instead.
2. Giving you back an array.

Calling set atrribute on an array will not work. It looks like what you want to do instead is something like:

```html
<div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://eatforklore.typeform.com/to/XPDPsx?p1=xxxxx&amp;p2=xxxxx&amp;p3=xxxxx&amp;p4=xxxxx" data-text="Mo. 1 Product Reviews" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<script>// <![CDATA[
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('typeform-widget');
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i ++)
  a[i].setAttribute('data-url','https://eatforklore.typeform.com/to/XPDPsx?p1=' + p1);

(function(){var qs,js,q,s,d=document,gi=d.getElementById,ce=d.createElement,gt=d.getElementsByTagName,id='typef_orm',b='https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/share.typeform.com/';if(!gi.call(d,id)){js=ce.call(d,'script');js.id=id;js.src=b+'widget.js';q=gt.call(d,'script')[0];q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q)}})()
// ]]></script>
```

Edit: To follow up a bit, `getElmentsByTagName` would be useful if you wanted to get every `div` on the page, but your code is using a class name and not a tag name.

Edit 2: Fixed for loop - thanks for pointing out my oversight @JPO :)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` selects nodes base on their tag, not their class. For example, if I wanted to select all the links on a page, I would use:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

@ian-mundy is right to suggest `getElementsByClassName`, but there's an error in the for-loop. It should look like:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('typeform-widget');
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var link = a[i];
    link.setAttribute('data-url','https://eatforklore.typeform.com/to/XPDPsx?p1=' + p1);
}
```